# Which options should i choose in MinGW setup for a complete c and c++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, mingw, installation

I am trying to setup MinGW with NetBeans IDE.
I've downloaded mingw-get-setup.exe but i do not understand which packages should i choose for c and c++ compiler.
please help

Comment: This is not MinGW help forum/website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For basic C/C++ installation you can choose following options from Installation Manager as highlighted :

[image]

Msys-Base is not necessary